# Is it ok to use Mongo's "Object ID" as its unique identifier? If so, how can I convert it to a string and look it up by string?

Tags: mongodb, database

For example...

```
user/view/?id=324gijsdfi3h25o1
```

I can `str()` it...but...

How can I `find` it up by string?

**Edit: I want each document in Mongo to have a unique identifier (usually a string) that I can look up on. I was hoping the Object ID could be this (since it has a lot of letter and it's unique.) And I want it to work with HTTP GET. view?uid=e93jfsb0e3jflskdjf**

Comment: Can you clarify the question by providing what the docs do not answer for you: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can construct a new `ObjectId` using the string. This example uses the MongoDB console:

```
db.users.find({ _id: ObjectId("4cdfb11e1f3c000000007822") })
```

I can't tell from your question which language driver you are using (if any at all), but most drivers also support this functionality.

You should NOT convert the `ObjectId` in the database to a string, and then compare it to another string. If you'd do this, MongoDB cannot use the `_id` index and it'll have to scan all the documents, resulting in poor query performance.

Comment: How else should I compare it to other strings, if I don't use the ObjectID as the unique identifier?

Comment: @TIMEX: What do you mean? Could you update your question to explain exactly what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want each document in Mongo to have a unique identifier (usually a string) that I can look up on.  I was hoping the Object ID could be this (since it has a lot of letter and it's unique.)    I'm building a blog, and I want it to work with HTTP GET.  view?uid=e93jfsb0e3jflskdjf

Answer (score 17):

To your questions:

> Is it ok to use Mongo's “Object ID” as its unique identifier?

Yes, it is intended for this purpose. Making unique IDs can be a pain in sharded environments, so MongoDB does this for you.

> If so, how can I convert it to a string and look it up by string?

Don't. It's not a string. MongoDB actually lets you override the default ID. So if you start searching for `#"4cdfb11e1f3c000000007822"`, Mongo thinks that you're looking for a string. If instead you look for `ObjectId("4cdfb11e1f3c000000007822")`, Mongo will look for the ObjectId (or MongoID).

In your question, it looks like you're trying to pass it in as a string. How you convert this to an "objectid" will depend on your driver. PHP has a [MongoId](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoid.php). Other drivers have a similar function.

Answer (score 0):

ObjectId is a handy way of generating a unique _id, but you are free to do it yourself. For your example,

```
var o = {_id: Math.random().toString(36).substring(10)};
collection.insert(o, handleCollision);
```

works fine, though you have to handle collisions yourself. Then you can use direct string comparisons as needed.